# Javascript doesnt wait to read json file

Tags: javascript

I want to read a json file but when I use await it seems to not wait for the file to get into the var

I have this code:

```
var webshopItems;
window.addEventListener('load', Initieer);

function Initieer() {
      ReadJSON();
      console.log(webshopItems[0].Name)
};

const ReadJSON = () => {
  let path = 'js/webshopItems.json';
  (async () => {
        webshopItems = await(GetJSON(path));
  })()
}

const GetJSON = async (file) => {
    let response = await fetch(file);
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

So when I try this code webshopItems is undefined when i try to get the name.
The name is correct because if i debug at somepoint it will get loaded just not in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you're not waiting for the response.

```
var webshopItems;
window.addEventListener('load', Initieer);

async function Initieer() {
      await ReadJSON();
      console.log(webshopItems[0].Name)
};

const ReadJSON = async () => {
  let path = 'js/webshopItems.json';
  webshopItems = await(GetJSON(path));
}

const GetJSON = async (file) => {
    let response = await fetch(file);
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: just for clarification because i didnt see it the first time: ReadJSON the inner async is removed and readjson() is now an async